# Simple javascript code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am wondering why javascript alerts doesn't popup:

asp.asp file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AAA</title>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

  <script class="code" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#btn-statistika" ).click({
                alert('ok');
            });
            $( "#btn-lokality" ).click({
                alert('ok');
            });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<button class='ui-state-default' id='btn-statistika' style='' >Statistika</button>
<button class='ui-state-default' id='btn-lokality' style='' >Lokality</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Another asp files are working, I don't know why this cannot work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a function as param to `click()` call

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn-statistika").click(function () {
        alert('ok');
    });
    $("#btn-lokality").click(function () {
        alert('ok');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the updated code**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>AAA</title>

   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

  <script class="code" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $( "#btn-statistika" ).click(function(){
                alert('ok');
            });
            $( "#btn-lokality" ).click(function(){
                alert('ok');
            });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<button class='ui-state-default' id='btn-statistika' style='' >Statistika</button>
<button class='ui-state-default' id='btn-lokality' style='' >Lokality</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Note: You need to pass a **function()** in **click({});** event.